# Disable menu selection after activate the plugin function

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am writing an eclipse plug-in and when I right click and select the Plug-in from the menu,it activate perfectly.

I need to disable that selection after that plugin is activated.

```
    <action
           label="Plugin Launcher"
           class="plugin.model.ExecutePlugin"
           menubarPath="test1.menu1/group1"
           enablesFor="*"
           icon="icons/Icon.jpg"
           id="test.newAction">
     </action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your action delegate code can just call the `setEnabled(boolean)` on the `IAction` object in the `run` or `selectionChanged` methods.

Comment: NO it didn't worked...

I want to Freeze the Eclipse actions within the time that activating my plugin